# How can I solve "Method not Allowed" in Heroku deploy

Tags: python, flask, heroku, telegram-bot

I recently tried to deploy my telegram bot on **Heroku** and I use **Flask** framework for write webhook code. With using "git push heroku master" deploying my codes began with any problems, But at the end I encountered this problem that the link "https://git.heroku.com/serene-crag-92322.git" I get **"Method Not Allowed"** message. Please help me to solve this problem and thank you in advance.
My Flask code:

```
@app.route('/' + TOKEN, methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
    bot.process_new_updates([update])
    return "!", 200


@app.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(
        url='https://gentle-temple-77151.herokuapp.com/' + TOKEN)
    return "!", 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The message from Heroku:

[image: The message from Heroku:]

Comment: maybe it need both methods - `methods=['GET', 'POST']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku creates a git repository with your source code before building and deploying your code. You had tried to access that private Git repository, which is not accessible to the outside world (therefore, the `Method Not Allowed` error message appeared). But the actual website where your web app is deployed is different. That web app includes your app name, if you had given one during Heroku app creation, else a random name is given to your web app.

Heroku Git Repository Link: https://git.heroku.com/serene-crag-92322.git

Deployed Heroku App Link: http://serene-crag-92322.herokuapp.com/